# Gradient of Vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

What would be the gradient of the following vectors in Cartesian coordinate?

$$\mathrm{grad} (\vec{c} \cdot \vec{r})\, ,$$

where $\vec{c}$ is the constant vector and $\vec{r}$ is the radius vector.

Comment: Is the _radius vector_ just $\vec x$ (I mean, the usual variable you use in functions $f:\ \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$), or some sort of unit vector?

Comment: @DavideF yeah.. just a position vector not a unit vector.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, $\vec c\cdot\vec r$ isn't a vector but a scalar function, so with $\vec r$ being the variable, $\vec c\cdot\vec r$ can be seen as a function from $\mathbb R^n$ ($n$ is the number of components of $\vec r$: if you're looking at it as a position vector, it might be $n=1$, $2$ or $3$) to $\mathbb R$.

Since $\vec c\cdot\vec r=\sum_{i=1}^nc_ir_i$, you have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r_k}\sum_{i=1}^nc_ir_i=c_k,
$$
so by the definition of the gradient you have $\nabla(\vec c\cdot\vec r)=\vec c$.